# How do i tell elRte to not replace/mess my Tenjin tags?

Tags: javascript, elrte

When i'm inserting code like:

```
<?rb some_enumerator.each do |item| ?>
#{ item.name }
<?rb end ?>
```

it is replaced by:

```
<!--?rb some_enumerator.each do |item| ?-->
#{ item.name }
<!--?rb end ?-->
```

any opts to prohibit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need custom `restore` callback in your opts.

Something like this:

```
var opts = {
  restore : [function(html) {
    return html.replace(/<!--\?rb\s+([^>]+)\s+\?-->/gi, function(t, statement) {
      return "<?rb " + statement + " ?>";
    });
  }]
}

$('your-selector').elrte(opts);
```

elRte will still replace your tags but you'll fix them back via `retore` callback.